# Mongo: Get last item bought in store for multiple users in one query

Tags: mongodb, distinct

Lets say I have a collection users:

`{ name: "John", id: 1 }
{ name: "Snow", id: 2 }`

And both are customers of my shop, the items they bought I have in another collection

`{ buyer: 1, item: 'winter_clothes', date: 0001 }
{ buyer: 2, item: 'sword', date: 0002 }
{ buyer: 1, item: 'direwolf_puppy_food', date: 0002 }`

(date would be some sort of timestamp)

Can I with one query, for all my customers get the last item both bought?

I thought I could do this with [distinct](https://www.w3resource.com/mongodb/shell-methods/collection/db-collection-distinct.php), but that doesn't seem to do the same thing as in MySQL.

Comment: You can easily do this with `$lookup` and `$sort` aggregation

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below aggregation pipeline as reference to achieve what you are looking for :

```
db.customers.aggregate([{'$lookup':
 {
   'from': 'items',
   'localField': 'id',
   'foreignField':'buyer',
   'as': 'details'
 }},{'$unwind':'$details'},
 {'$sort':{'name':-1,'details.date':-1}},
 {'$group':{'_id':'$name','details':{'$first':'$details'}}}])
```